# Escape quotes inside quoted fields when parsing CSV in Flink

Tags: csv, apache-flink

In Flink, parsing a CSV file using readCsvFile raises an exception when encountring a field containing quotes like `"Fazenda São José ""OB"" Airport"`:

```
org.apache.flink.api.common.io.ParseException: Line could not be parsed: '191,"SDOB","small_airport","Fazenda São José ""OB"" Airport",-21.425199508666992,-46.75429916381836,2585,"SA","BR","BR-SP","Tapiratiba","no","SDOB",,"SDOB",,,'
```

I've found in [this](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Read-CSV-Parse-Quoted-Strings-Function-td2500.html) mailing list thread and [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-2567) JIRA issue that quoting inside the field should be realized through the \ character, but I don't have control over the data to modify it. Is there a way to work around this?

I've also tried using `ignoreInvalidLines()` (which is the less preferable solution) but it gave me the following error:

```
08:49:05,737 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.common.io.LocatableInputSplitAssigner    - Assigning remote split to host localhost
08:49:05,765 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask                  - Error in task code:  CHAIN DataSource (at main(Job.java:53) (org.apache.flink.api.java.io.TupleCsvInputFormat)) -> Map (Map at main(Job.java:54)) -> Combine(SUM(1), at main(Job.java:56) (2/8)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.GenericCsvInputFormat.skipFields(GenericCsvInputFormat.java:443)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.GenericCsvInputFormat.parseRecord(GenericCsvInputFormat.java:412)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.CsvInputFormat.readRecord(CsvInputFormat.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.DelimitedInputFormat.nextRecord(DelimitedInputFormat.java:454)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.CsvInputFormat.nextRecord(CsvInputFormat.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.invoke(DataSourceTask.java:176)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:559)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my code:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> csvInput = env.readCsvFile("resources/airports.csv")
            .ignoreFirstLine()
            .ignoreInvalidLines()
            .parseQuotedStrings('"')
            .includeFields("100000001")
            .types(String.class, String.class)
            .map((Tuple2<String, String> value) -> new Tuple2<>(value.f1, 1))
            .groupBy(0)
            .sum(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the input data, then you should turn off `parseQuotedString()`. This will simply look for the next field delimiter and return everything in between as a string (including the quotations marks). Then you can remove the leading and trailing quotation mark in a subsequent map operation.

Comment: If I turn off `parseQuotedString()`, lines with fields containing the field delimiter will not be correctly parsed. I need to ignore both quotes and commas inside fields.

Comment: Hmm that's a problem. Then I guess you should transform your input data so that internal quotes are escaped. But, admittedly, we could also try to implement this feature within Flink by simply counting how many quoting characters one has already seen. But at the moment this is not supported.